# How do I control the order of execution of tests from Excel in Maven?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have the similar issue. I have 3 different suites (TestSetup(Making the system ready), Sanity & Regression) and when i am controlling the Test cases from Excel with Yes/No flags. But when i enable all the TC's in all suites in excel, the execution order is Random. I tried with all the parameters in but no luck. At any cost TestSetup suite should execute first followed by other suites. Note: Execution flow is proper when I ran from Eclipse editor.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Any one plz assist me on this.